# AsyncStorage with redux store

Tags: react-native, redux, asyncstorage

I am using Redux to manage the cart state but on restarting the app, the cart state becomes empty. To resolve, I thought of using AsyncStorage to store the data and get it in componentDidMount but it shows null instead of the cart data.

***REDUX ACTION CODE***

```
case 'ADD_TO_CART':
       {
           const updatedCart = [...state.cart];
           const item = updatedCart.find(x=>x.key===action.payload.key);
           if(item)
           {
            item.count++;
           }
           else{
             updatedCart.push(action.payload);
           }
           AsyncStorage.setItem('cart',{...state,cart: updatedCart,total: state.total + 1})
            return {
                ...state,
                cart: updatedCart,
                total: state.total + 1,
               
            }
       }
```

***FETCHING DATA***

```
async componentDidMount() {
     const item = await AsyncStorage.getItem('cart'))
     console.log(item)
  }
```

I have one more action to delete the cart item in which the same setItem method is used to set the cart state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set an Object to Async storage it should be a string not an object, so use a JSON.strigify and set the item like below

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('cart',JSON.stringify({...state,cart: updatedCart,total: state.total + 1}));
```

When you get the item use JSON.parse() to parse them item like below

```
   const item = await AsyncStorage.getItem('cart'))
     console.log(JSON.parse(item))
```

As your requirement is to persist the redux state consider using
https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist
Which will persist the state when you close the app.

Comment: Thanks for this. I just checked my note of AsyncStorage and this string and object one was noted but all I did was just set it and get it. I will surely read about redux-persist but guide me one thing does AsyncStorage can't fulfill the requirement.

Comment: When you use Asyn storage you will have to save and retrieve each and every type manually lets say you want to favorite an item then you will have to maintain another key, set and get it and update redux state, but persist does this for you and saves a lot of effort